# how to set text left of relatvie layout in android

Tags: android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:id="@+id/rl_main"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffff" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativelayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp" >

        <com.lociiapp.utils.RoundedImageView
            android:id="@+id/notificationuserimage"
            android:layout_width="46dp"
            android:layout_height="46dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="17dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="17dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="17dp" />

            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/desc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/notificationuserimage"
            android:fontFamily="calibri"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:text="Request For Travlling to You"
            android:textColor="#888686"
            android:textSize="15dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/revresetime"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/desc"
            android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/notificationuserimage"
            android:textColor="#c9cdd0"
            android:textSize="12dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="17dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/rejecticon" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView1"
            android:background="#e0e0e0" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/view1"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/accepticon" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my xml I am trying to set one Relative-layout always come right of other relative layout when Relative Layout visibility and in single text-view text auto adjust when other Relative Layout invisible. Please help me where I am doing wrong ? please find the [attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47XCZ.png). There is Text-view collapse.

Comment: You could have 1) the root layout be a LinearLayout with horizonatal orientation 2) set weight 1 of first RelativeLayout 3) set weight 0 of second RelativeLayout. If I understand your question correctly, that is

Comment: i want to set it in relative layout coz there is some condition  for which i ll have to use relative layout only

Comment: If you refer to the `android:layout_alignParentRight` of second RelativeLayout, then that is archived by my suggestion as the first Relative 'pushes' the second to the right to obtain as much space as possible (due to the weight being set to 1)

Comment: where i have to set actually i want to set relative-layout

Comment: can we set weight in relativelayout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:id="@+id/rl_main"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffff" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativelayout2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
 android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp" >

        <com.lociiapp.utils.RoundedImageView
            android:id="@+id/notificationuserimage"
            android:layout_width="46dp"
            android:layout_height="46dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="17dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="17dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="17dp" />

            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/desc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/notificationuserimage"
            android:fontFamily="calibri"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:text="Request For Travlling to You"
            android:textColor="#888686"
            android:textSize="15dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/revresetime"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/desc"
            android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/notificationuserimage"
            android:textColor="#c9cdd0"
            android:textSize="12dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginBottom="17dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/rejecticon" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView1"
            android:background="#e0e0e0" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/view1"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/accepticon" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: its fine But after hiding  linearlayout  and  desc textview text is not exteding to linearlayout   place

Comment: you mean visibility gone?

Comment: @Edge put android:visibility="gone" in your  android:id="@+id/linearlayout" and then check

Comment: after accept and reject imageview clcik  linearlayout becomes hiding in that case there is text print in desc text view which  should in  one line please check in attachment or in this screen http://i.stack.imgur.com/47XCZ.png

Comment: actually your attachment is not visible can you please add again?

Comment: seee there is notification come  like friend-request like facebook i cant set visibility  gone in xml

Comment: you can change visibility programatically if that is your concern

Comment: u saw my screen look  before accept and reject and and after accept and reject

Comment: yes I can see that what you can do is after accept or reject set your Linearlayout.setVisibility(View.gone) programatically so automatically your textview will take whole width then (with my xml changes).

Comment: http://paste.ofcode.org/fAAWQiCzZ8hdJrUNf6HqUH i did same  but its come in 2 line

Comment: wait let me clean the project

Comment: i see allsetVisibility(View.GONE) as commented code and setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); there you have to put holder.mylinearlayout.setVisibility(View.GONE) ;instead

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71487/discussion-between-kdeogharkar-and-edge).